# Best In Place Is not a function Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1, best-in-place

I'm working on a project in Rails 5.1.6 / ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
My problem is that, following step by step the documentation of the gem best_in_place I get an error.
Error:
[image]

I am a little complicated with the documentation since it is not fully explained how to implement the gem in Rails 5.
Any help is useful.
Thank you very much!

Important data:
assets / javascripts / application.js

[image]

assets / javascripts / use_best_in_place.js

[image]

Gemfile

[image]

gem list

views / layout / application.html.erb

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you loading jquery twice? One in application.js and other in views?

Try removing the one in views and it should work fine.

Comment: I had not considered that detail. Thank you very much!
PS: Several responded correctly, so thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from your application.html layout (jquery is already require inside application.js from `jquery-rails` gem):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

It should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

As per the description shared, need to change the
below mentioned configuration.

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

To this one

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: twice "jquery"? Why? Anyway, it keeps showing the same error :c

Comment: Sorry, typo just move the jquery above turbolinks...edited the answer as well

Comment: same error :/ Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).best_in_place is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Keep turbolinks after jquery always and try to load `best_in_place()` function after turbolinks loaded.

```
# application.js
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .

# assets / javascripts / use_best_in_place.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function(){ 
   jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
}
```

Comment: @JoséAntonioCamusGodoy have you `bundle install` it, also remove jquery from `application.html.erb` layout file.